# Different Visual Studio way to show an error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2022

So last time I've upgraded my vs studio 2019 to 2022. Everything was fine, but last time when I had an error, visual studio changed way showing it.
Normally in previous version, i could see in what line the problem is, by underlined code on red. But now it only pop ups one window:

[image]

> solution to this error is solved but i should see underlined line in code and description like in Visual Studio 2019

[image]

> Older error (taken from internet for an example):

Any solutions how to bring back older method showing underlined problem?

Comment: These are two unrelated situations. The first picture is a runtime error reported in the debugger, the second a syntax error.

Comment: it's visual example

Comment: So what is the problem you are experiencing? That the debugger does not show you the code where the exception occurs? Note that this will in no VS version be shown as red underline, so your question is really confusing and unclear.